# Error installing pygtk2 - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, gtk

I'm trying to install pygtk on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS with the following command

`sudo apt-get install python-gtk2-dev`

However, no matter what I do. I get the following error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package python-gtk2-dev.
(Reading database ... 490710 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-gtk2-dev_2.24.0-4ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-gtk2-dev (2.24.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python-gtk2-dev (2.24.0-4ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package python-gtk2-dev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-gtk2-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried solutions such as these described [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1), but to no avail. How can I fix this and install pygtk?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on clean 16.04 LTS installation. Please run `sudo apt-get install python-gtk2-dev --reinstall` and report the result.

Comment: I've had this issue on two different desktops on Ubuntu 16.04. Once I've updated all the packages via the ubuntu software updater the error disappeared. Not sure what the exact reason was.